# ekf_localization_node no output

Tags: localization, ekf, odometry, path, kalman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone
I am a beginner with ROS, and want to test things with the ekf_localization_node
(I use ROS Jade and Ubuntu 14.04)

So, I simulated a 2-wheeled robot in a 2D environment in Matlab.
Typically, a robot that goes away from its charging station to reach a target.
Now, I want to test the ekf_localization node to implement it soon on hardware(mobile robot with wheel encoders and gyro output signals), after I know it is at least possible

I extracted log files from my simulation (equivalent to odometry): x velocity, y velocity and yaw velocity.

image:![simulated path](/C:/Users/Karim Kouki/Desktop/traj1.png "indoor trajectory of the robot")

--> it was converted into a geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped to test it with the ekf_localization_node.
Here is my launchfile

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

 
  <param name="frequency" value="20"/>

 
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.06"/>


  <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>

 
  
  <!-- Defaults to "odom" if unspecified -->
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <!-- Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified -->
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <!-- Defaults to the value of "odom_frame" if unspecified -->
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

 <param name="twist0" value="/twist_input1"/> 
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  
     
  <rosparam param="twist0_config">[false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  true,  true, false,
                                  false, false, true,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>


  <param name="twist0_differential" value="true"/>

  <param name="twist0_relative" value="true"/>
 
  <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

  <!-- ======== ADVANCED PARAMETERS ======== -->

  <param name="twist0_queue_size" value="2"/>
  
  <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
  <!-- Defaults to "robot_localization_debug.txt" if unspecified. -->
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

  
  <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">[0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]</rosparam>

  
       <rosparam param="initial_estimate_covariance">[1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]</rosparam>




</node>
```

here you will find one example of a TwistWithCovarianceStamped message published over the topic /twist_input1
as input for the ekf_localization_node

```
  header: 
  seq: 534
  stamp: 
    secs: 1438178264
    nsecs: 22708520
  frame_id: odom
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 1.641866
      y: 1.472035
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.2307692
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

My problem is that I have no output of ekf_localization_node (even if I rostopic echo /odometry/filtered) after I rostopic echo /diagnostics,I am warned that yaw is not measured which could roughly "lead to unbounded error".

Actually, the tutorial suggested that with odometry input, x velocity, y velocity and yaw velocity should be the input data... I am quite confused now.

One other thing: I have no idea what to do for the covariance input matrix in the TwistWithCovarianceStamped message. Is it even useful?

Any idea what I did wrong?
Could you please give me some pieces of advice?

I am really looking forward to your answers

*EDIT: while removing the commentsof the launchfile I also removed the line param name="twist0" value="/twist_input1"(for the ros answers post), It was added in the edit*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214816/ekf_localization_node-no-output/) by [Cookie32](https://answers.ros.org/users/23100/cookie32/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your primary culprit is that you never tell the EKF what twist topic to look for. You tell it the configuration for `twist0`, but it needs to know what topic to listen on. You need this line in there:

```
<param name="twist0" value="/name/of/your/twist/topic"/>
```

Just replace the value with the name of whatever topic you're trying to use.

I need to fix that diagnostic message. It's really only a problem if you have infrequent absolute position measurements and are only measuring orientation differentially. You should be able to disregard it.

Also, the `differential` and `relative` parameters are meaningless for twist messages. They only apply to pose data.

EDIT in response to twist message post:

Is your twist message producing body-frame velocities (so, for example, if you drive forward, it's always +X), or is it producing world (odom) frame velocities (such that if you drive forward, you get +X, but then if you turn left and drive forward again, you get +Y velocity)? The issue is that your `frame_id` is set to *odom*, whereas velocities should be reported in *base_link*. All velocities that are fed into the EKF are transformed into `base_link` before being fused. Since the EKF itself is responsible for producing the *odom*->*base_link* transform, and it hasn't produced any output yet, no transform is available to work with your message.

Long story short: make sure your twist message is reported in the base_link (body) frame. See [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) for information about coordinate frames in ROS. Then change the `frame_id` in the header to *base_link* and try again.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cookie32](https://answers.ros.org/users/23100/cookie32/) on 2015-07-29**:
Thanks for your answer.
I edited the question (sorry for my mistake) and set the differential and relative parameters to false.
It still doesn't work. Any other idea?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-29**:
Do `rostopic echo /twist_input1` and post one message in your question.

Oh, and you can just remove the differential and relative parameters for the twist.

**Comment by [Cookie32](https://answers.ros.org/users/23100/cookie32/) on 2015-08-04**:
Thanks, now it does work, I have outuput to my Kalman filter with a TwistWithCovarianceStamped message as input.
Now, I'll consider a more complex model for two wheeled robot navigation thanks to this ekf_localization_node.